# Any simple way to check if two numbers have different signs?

Tags: c++, math, sign

I have two floating point number `a` and `b`. I want to check if they have different signs. The easy way is to see

```
bool b = a * b < 0;
```

But the two numbers are very small and a * b might be underflow. Any other simple way to check it?

Anyone thinking it is a duplicate question please give me an answer that exactly matches the condition `a * b < 0`. Note here the sign of 0 is undefined in my question.

Comment: c++11 has [signbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit). So, something `signbit(a) == signbit(b)` will be true with both have the same sign.

Comment: fwiw, vs2012 doesn't seem to have signbit. 2013 does, though.
can't you just multiply one number with a large number, like 1e20f? to ensure that the compiler doesn't reorder it, you can make a noinline function no_reorder that simply returns its argument, and then use no_reorder(a*1e20f)*b. 
or just cast one number to a double (if it isn't yet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [std::signbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) as follows:

```
bool c = std::signbit(a) == std::signbit(b);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1983ee7e859409b8)

Another way is to use [std::copysign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign) as follows:

```
bool c = std::copysign(a,b) == a;
```

Comment: not exact to check a*b < 0. a and b can be 0 also. Check (1) a = 1, b = 0 (2) a = -1, b = 0 Both should be false.

Comment: @user1899020 If I got your question right, both `signbit` and `copysign` detect the sign bit of zeroes, infinities, and NaNs.

Comment: @user1899020 a and b should be false as side effect of your "fast check" but does not mean it should be false for different signs

Comment: Two follow-up questions: 1. How does performance compare with OP multiplication-based comparison? 2. How to deal with +0 versus -0 having different sign despite being equal (and therefore "having the same everything, including the sign" for the purpose of most applications)?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is:

bool c = ((0 > a) == (0 > b));